# A simple regex match

Tags: c#, regex

I have (from long ago) problems with regex matching...
(I simply can't understand and remeber this damn thing...)

However, i'd like to find a string that is the end or a table row and the beginning of another row:

```
<tr>(-line-break or spaces or both...)</tr>
```

I am trying with

```
Regex.Match(_mainTable, @"</tr>*<tr>")
```

but it returns Empty

Comment: `*` is saying the previous character (i.e. the `>`) is matched zero or more times.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  It may be better to use something that parses the DOM rather than trying to parse using regex.

Comment: You are better using something more appropriate, like the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: your example and description are different. Did you want to match from the ending `tr` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `*` is a quantifier. That means zero or more of the **previous** match, which in your expression is the `>` that appears before the `*` .. what you what is to match "any spaces" the is indicated by the abreviation `\s` which is a shortcut for: any character in the set `[ \t\r\n]`

so your code should be

```
Regex.Match(_mainTable, @"</tr>\s*<tr>")
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `\s*` to match inbetween newline character.

```
Regex.Match(_mainTable, @"</tr>\s*<tr>")
```